# Share data api with BehaviorSubject - architecture Observables Store

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

**I would just like to make a call in the api and reuse the data in an observable, like a kind of store like in redux.**

**API URL:** http://demo5095413.mockable.io/consolidado

****Stackblitz project** :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iy9zhv?file=src/app/core.service.ts

Service responsible for connection with api

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConsolidadoApi {
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getInvestiments(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<PosicaoConsolidada>(`${environment.basePosicaoConsolidada}`)
      .pipe(
        map(res => res),
        shareReplay(),
      )
  }
}
```

Service where the data is processed, my facade layer(store)
Initially this way, this observable is responsible for making the call in the api. At the end of it I issue a BehaviorSubject

```
export class CoreService {

    private subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
    investment$: Observable<any> = this.subject.asObservable();
    
    constructor(private api: ConsolidadoApi, private loadingService: LoadingService, public messagesService: MessagesService, public state: StateService) {
        this.getInvesmentsPortifolio$()
     }

    public getInvesmentsPortifolio$(): Observable<Carteiras> {
        return this.api.getInvestiments()
            .pipe(
                map(response => response.carteiras),
                catchError(err => {
                    const message = "Error Investments";
                    this.messagesService.showErrors(message);
                    console.log(message,err);
                    return throwError(err);
                }),
                tap(investment$ => this.subject.next(investment$))
            )
    }
```

That's how I would like to do it, access the observable that already has all the investment portfolios and from there create an observable from the investment portfolio "Agora"

```
getPortifolioAgora(): Observable<any> {
    return this.investment$
        .pipe(
            map(response => response.carteiras.find(
                carteira => carteira.tipoInvestimento === "AGORA"
            ))
        );
}
```

But in my component dont work

```
    constructor(public coreService: CoreService, private loadingService: LoadingService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData()
  }

  public loadData(){
    this.loadingService.loadingOn()
    
    this.coreService.getPortifolioAgora().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })

    this.coreService.getInvesmentsPortifolio$().subscribe(res => {
      this.carteiras = res
      console.log('All portifolio investments----->',res)
    })

  }
```

[image]
Properties undefined?

**I know if i do it that way the find works.**

```
// In this observable I access directly in the api and I can access the investment portfolio Agora
// it's working, but I wouldn't want to do it that way because I would have made another call on the server
public portifolioAgora$(): Observable<Carteiras> {
    return this.api.getInvestiments()
        .pipe(
            map(response => response.carteiras.find(
                carteira => carteira.tipoInvestimento === "AGORA"
            )),
            finalize(() => this.loadingService.loadingOff())
            //tap(data => console.log(data, JSON.stringify(data)))
        )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in `getInvesmentsPortifolio$()` you are adding only `carteiras` array into `BehaviourSubject` So, inside `getPortifolioAgora` update map code to

```
 getPortifolioAgora(): Observable<any> {
    return this.investment$.pipe(
      map((response) =>
        response.find((carteira) => carteira.tipoInvestimento === 'AGORA')
      )
    );
  }
```

Also the problem can be you are calling `getPortifolioAgora` before `getInvesmentsPortifolio$`, the result will not be available in `Subject` at very initial load

Comment: I dont understand. Where would I make this change, as I understand you asked me to change the function I don't want to use, the one that worked. I would like to reuse in component the getPortifolioAgora() not  portifolioAgora$(). I create project in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iy9zhv?file=src/app/core.service.ts

Could you show me by stackblitz, pls?

Comment: Yeah, i was talking about `getPortifolioAgora` method

Comment: Look inside `getInvesmentsPortifolio$()` you are mapping response to `response.carteiras`, so now after `map` pipe every pipe after it will receive `carteiras` array, not `response.carteiras`, And this -> `tap((investment$) => this.subject.next(investment$))` will then add `carteiras` array inside `BehavoiurSubject` not whole response object. But if you see `getPortifolioAgora` method you are doing `response.carteiras` to find result but it should be just `carteiras` because you have array inside `Subject` not response object. hope you got what i mean to say

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-egpuvz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcore.service.ts Here I'm not able to get data from the endpoint so `find` will return undefined, but you can check the code here.

Comment: very strange, this is undefined even with the api working here. I believe the investments$ are taking too long to load when requested in the getPortifolioAgora() method, you know how I do it?

Comment: @GuilhermeLucas Actually we need to subscribr inside CoreService or else it will never trigger. `constructor(private api: ConsolidadoApi) {
    this.getInvesmentsPortifolio$().subscribe();
  }`

Comment: Thank you very much! that was exactly it!

Answer (score 0):

@[navnath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6099811/navnath) Answered my question, putting it here to make it clear

`investments$` was coming undefined in getPortifolioAgora() because getInvesmentsPortifolio$() not subscribe in constructor.

the constructor has to stay that way:

```
constructor(private api: ConsolidadoApi, private loadingService: LoadingService, public messagesService: MessagesService, public state: StateService) {
    this.getInvesmentsPortifolio$().subscribe()
 }
```

And

```
 getPortifolioAgora(): Observable<any> {
    return this.investment$.pipe(
      map((response) =>
        response.find((carteira) => carteira.tipoInvestimento === 'AGORA')
      )
    );
  }
```